# SpatiaLite: Distance returns NULL when geometries touch

Tags: spatialite

I use the Python sqlite3 library as well as the SQLite3 CLI.
I am also using the [Distance](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p13) function with the `use_ellipsoid` parameter, to get the distance between two geometries in meters.

Whenever the geometries touch, I get NULL instead of 0.0 m distance. The exact value of `use_ellipsoid` does not matter.

An example:

```
.load 'mod_spatialite.so'
SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);
SELECT DISTANCE(MakePoint(13.41, 52.525), MakePoint(13.41, 52.525), 1);
```

It just returns NULL, respectively, None in Python. If I change one of the points, everything seems to work fine, so it is not a CRS issue.

Is this supposed to be like this? Am I doing or expecting something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is your SpatiaLite version? The query works for me with SpatiaLite 5.0.0-beta0 but not with version 4.3.0a.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I run libspatialite 4.3.0a. The fact that it works with 5.0.0 beta is interesting.

Comment: SpatiaLite is a project that is under continuous development. It might be good if the list of the SQL functions had a field to tell since which version the newest functions are available. This list http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html, despite the title of the page, has many functions which were not in 4.3.0.

Comment: I edited my question to contain a more precise link to the [docs for 4.3.0](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p13). However, this changes nothing about my expectations towards `Distance`. I'll consider this as a bug then.

Comment: It may be a bug but I do not believe that it will be fixed ever into the 4.3 version.